# MySQL JOIN query with conditions

Tags: mysql, join

Current database structure includes:

1. Countries (country_id, country_name)
2. Towns (town_id, country_id, town_name)
3. Areas (area_id, town_id, area_name)
4. Stations (station_id, area_id, station_name)
5. Offers (offer_id, offer_name, stations)

Stations column in table Offers include station ids in a format like:

|station_id_1|station_id_2|station_id_4|......|

I am quite familiar with JOINED queries but in this case its hard to create a single query that can COUNT(country_id) FROM countries OR town_id FROM towns that actually have an offer... how can i JOIN stations column FROM offers table with the actual stations in order to JOIN lower level tables afterwards? is this possible?

thank you in advance

Comment: i removed my answer, you should add n-to-n table `offers_stations (offer_id, station_id)` and connect offers and stations. keeping things like this `station_id_1|station_id_2|station_id_4` is NEVER good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query would give you the distinct number of countries that have offers. The `Offers` and the `Stations` table are joined using the `LIKE` operator, as below:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT country_id)  
FROM
    Offers O
INNER JOIN Stations S
ON O.stations LIKE '%'||S.station_id||'%'
INNER JOIN Areas A
ON S.area_id = A.area_id
INNER JOIN Towns T
ON A.town_id = T.town_id
INNER JOIN Countries C
ON T.country_id = C.country_id;
```

However, like Peter suggests, it is not a recommended practice to store station_id data in a concatenated format.

Comment: For info, why is it necessary to use a LIKE operator?

Comment: @Simon Even though it is not the recommended db design, the stations column currently contains data, such as 'station_id_1|station_id_2|station_id_4'. To match any of the station_id's contained therein, LIKE is used.

Comment: Worked like a charm. However it needed COUNT(DISTINCT countries.country_id). Thank you very much @JosephB and all of you for your help. Will bear in mind to use separate records next time to avoid concatenated format.

Comment: for the record, after numerous tests (and a bit more reasearch) i have replaced LIKE '%'||S.station_id||'%' with LIKE CONCAT('%|', S.station_id, '|%') which made the day :-)

Comment: @NickZulu Yeah, using CONCAT is a better way to do the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the comment made by @Peter, you do have a case to an intermediate table. The reason is that a station may have multiple offers and an offer may be applicable to multiple stations. Therefore, if you later wish to store additional columns in the offers table, this data will be duplicated throughout the table. Normalising, by adding an intermediary will minimise this duplication and reduce overhead should you wish to update any information - E.g. offer discount etc.

With credit to @Joseph B, his query would then become something like:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT country_id)  
FROM
    Offers O
INNER JOIN Offers_Stations OS
ON OS.offer_id = O.offer_id
INNER JOIN Stations S
ON OS.station_id = S.station_id
INNER JOIN Areas A
ON S.area_id = A.area_id
INNER JOIN Towns T
ON A.town_id = T.town_id
INNER JOIN Countries C
ON T.country_id = C.country_id;
```